# How do I efficiently recode groups of dummies conditional on one dummy?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, vectorization, dummy-variable

I'm trying to recode several dummy variables at once but am struggling to come up with a functioning vectorized solution (alternatively a for loop).

**reprex**:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(dummies)
library(janitor)

df_raw <- data.frame(
  species = as.factor(c("cat", "dog", NA, "dog", "dog")),
  weight = rnorm(5, mean = 5, sd = 1),
  sex = as.factor(c("m", NA, "f", "f", "m"))
)

df_raw

  species   weight  sex
1     cat 3.025896    m
2     dog 3.223064 <NA>
3    <NA> 5.230367    f
4     dog 4.231511    f
5     dog 5.819032    m
```

I split the factor variables (`species` and `sex`) into dummies but the `NA` get their own indicators (`species_na` and `sex_na`)

```
df_dummy <- dummies::dummy.data.frame(df_raw,
                                      dummy.classes = "factor",
                                      sep = "_",
                                      omit.constants = TRUE,
                                      all = TRUE) %>% 
  janitor::clean_names()

  species_cat species_dog species_na   weight sex_f sex_m sex_na
1           1           0          0 3.025896     0     1      0
2           0           1          0 3.223064     0     0      1
3           0           0          1 5.230367     1     0      0
4           0           1          0 4.231511     1     0      0
5           0           1          0 5.819032     0     1      0
```

**My problem**: how do I efficiently recode all of the factor dummies ("indexed" by the prefix, e.g. `species_`) to NA conditional on value of the `_na` dummy in the respective group of dummies? In other words, I need to mutate all dummies with the prefix `species_` as `NA` whenever the `species_na == 1` etc.

I have come up with the solution below, but I haven't been able to generalize the last step to the entire dataset

```
factor_vars <- dplyr::select_if(df_raw, is.factor) %>% colnames()
na_labs <- paste(factor_vars,
                 "na",
                 sep = "_")

df_dummy <- df_dummy %>%
  dplyr::mutate(across(all_of(na_labs),
                       .fns = list(var = ~ . == 1),
                       .names = "{fn}_{col}" ))  

# --- trial run for one variable only
test <- df_dummy %>% 
  mutate(species_cat = ifelse(var_species_na == TRUE,
                              NA,
                              species_cat))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why are you doing this? Can't you just make `NA` a factor level `"NA"`, set contrasts and use the `model.matrix` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df_dummy <- dummies::dummy.data.frame(df_raw,
                                      dummy.classes = "factor",
                                      sep = "_",
                                      omit.constants = TRUE,
                                      all = TRUE) %>% 
  janitor::clean_names()

factor_vars <- dplyr::select_if(df_raw, is.factor) %>% colnames()
na_labs <- paste(factor_vars,
                 "na",
                 sep = "_")


map_dfc(factor_vars, ~df_dummy %>%
      select(contains(.x)) %>%
      mutate(across(.fns = ~ifelse(.data[[paste0(.x, '_na')]] == 1, NA, .))))

#  species_cat species_dog species_na sex_f sex_m sex_na
#1           1           0          0     0     1      0
#2           0           1          0    NA    NA     NA
#3          NA          NA         NA     1     0      0
#4           0           1          0     1     0      0
#5           0           1          0     0     1      0
```

Comment: Thanks, Ronak Shah! One minor issue: it's not stable across datasets where one or more factors have no NAs. I guess a fix would be to subset the factor_vars vector to omit these?

Comment: `factor_vars <- dplyr::select_if(df_raw,
                                is.factor) %>% 
  colnames()

has_NAs <- sapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x))) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column("variable") %>% 
  dplyr::rename(count = '.') %>% 
  filter(count > 0)

factor_vars <- factor_vars[factor_vars%in% has_NAs$variable] `

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
df_dummy <- df_dummy %>% 
  mutate(across(c(starts_with("species")), ~ factor(ifelse(species_na == 1, NA, .)))) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(starts_with("sex")), ~ factor(ifelse(sex_na == 1, NA, .))))

df_dummy

  species_cat species_dog species_na   weight sex_f sex_m sex_na
1           1           0          0 4.879161     0     1      0
2           0           1          0 5.960176  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>
3        <NA>        <NA>       <NA> 5.189566     1     0      0
4           0           1          0 5.165760     1     0      0
5           0           1          0 5.952365     0     1      0
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry I didn't specify so above but the reprex is a made up example, I'm looking for a solution that holds across a much wider dataset

Answer (score 1):

I have a package on github [{dplyover}](https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover) which can create dummy variables in an `across`-like manner. Below we select all factor variables with `where(is.factor)` and apply to each column `dist_value` which is a wrapper around `unique` which returns all non-`NA` values. The function in `.fns` takes each selected column as `.x` and applies to it each of the unique values from `dist_values` as `.y`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover) # https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover

df_raw %>% 
  mutate(crossover(where(is.factor),
                   dist_values,
                   .fns = ~ if_else(.y == .x, 1, 0)))

#>   species   weight  sex species_cat species_dog sex_f sex_m
#> 1     cat 5.281178    m           1           0     0     1
#> 2     dog 4.343656 <NA>           0           1    NA    NA
#> 3    <NA> 4.555380    f          NA          NA     1     0
#> 4     dog 4.990039    f           0           1     1     0
#> 5     dog 4.988497    m           0           1     0     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>